# Ingesting Data Sketches from Presto into Druid

Tags: presto, druid

I am trying to ingest a dataset (S3 & parquet format) that has a HLL Data Sketch built from Presto engine.
When I ingest it into durid using HLLSketchMerge, it's failing as I have tried all 3 types "tgtHllType" (HLL_4, HLL_6, and HLL_8). I believe both engines are using the same methodology for data sketches. I can use "HLLSketchBuild" to build a HLL data Sketch, but I want to avoid that if possible as it's already pre-processed from a different engine (Presto).  Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.
https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/datasketches-hll.html
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/hyperloglog.html

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read the tour [tour] and  [ask] a question.  You are much more likely to get a useful answer if you reformat your question to be more easily read.

Comment: First question would be whether Presto and Druid store HLLs in the same format. This i do not know, however. If  you do not get an answer here, you can try asking on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html) as well.